# search feature not working for my php app. I keep getting syntax error

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Trying to get a search function to work I keep getting syntax error not sure if I am doing it right to begin with. I have few columns id, name,status, lanId and comments The table is called requests. Just need little help trying to figure it out. I don't think the word search is correct that I have in there. I just don't understand how to create search feature for my app.

```
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="search.php">
      <table width="599" border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Keyword
          <input name="var1" type="text" id="var1">
          <input type="submit" value="Search"></th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <?php



    $serverName = "xx.xx.xxx.xxx";
    // Connect to MSSQL via PDO
    try {
    $db= new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=systems_requests", "xxx", "xxx");
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    { 
    die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) ); 

    $var1 = str_replace(array('%','_'),'',$_POST['var1']);
    if (!$var1)
    {
        exit('Invalid form value: '.$var1);
    }


    $query = "SELECT * FROM requests WHERE status='Received' LIKE :search";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':search', '%' . $var1 . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    /* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set 
    print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");*/


     $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach( $result as $row ) {
        echo $row["id"];
        echo $row["status"];
        echo $row["name"];
        echo $row["lanId"];
      echo $row["comments"];
    }




    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Ok so I changed it up a bit the page is showing up but Now I am getting an errorsqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="search.php">
  <table width="599" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Keyword
      <input name="var1" type="text" id="var1">
      <input type="submit" value="Search"></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<?php
require_once("../includes/db_connect.php");
$var1 = $_POST['var1'];

$query  = "select * from requests where comments like '%" . $var1 . "%'";

if( $stmt === false)
{
     echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


  while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo 'Id: '.$row['id'];
    echo '<br/> name: '.$row['name'];
    echo '<br/> lanId: '.$row['lanId'];
    echo '<br/> comments: '.$row['comments'];

}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: syntax error from WHAT? php? mssql?

Comment: Please avoid giving your actual credentials. Ps. what errors are you encountering?

Comment: Did you really just post your username and password for your database on the internet?

Comment: ahem `WHERE status='Received' LIKE :search";` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html --- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: @SeanLange: not like it'd be useful, since the provided IP is in a private block anyways.

Comment: Your query as posted doesn't make any sense. You have a where clause with a single search predicate. then you have LIKE just tossed in there. You need to include "and SomeColumn like searchvalue"

Comment: True @MarcB but seriously...

Comment: The credentals are fake and ip address is fake also

Comment: throw in an `AND|OR` in there ;-) and magic should happen, depending on the search criteria. Plus, possibly checking if POST is set/not empty, which seems to be all running inside the same file. Error reporting should be throwing you an undefined index notice, if that's the case. Besides your syntax error in the query there Donny.

Comment: ok, well.... I've said enough to get you to fix that. @ me if you need me, I'll be moving on. *arrivederci!* - edit: oh, and notice the upvotes my comments received ;-) I think they speak for themselves.

Comment: I am not getting the page to show at all it comes up with error

Comment: sorry Donny, but you'll need to post the actual error(s), we're not mindreaders, least I'm not. Update your question with what you're using now and maybe somebody else will pick up on it. Re-read my comments.

Comment: will do sorry I was using the statement bellow durbnposin gave me I get ? is syntax error. I posted it bellow.

Comment: well he's given you a (pardon the expression), bum steer.

Comment: here `WHERE status='Received' AND LIKE :search"` or  `WHERE status='Received' OR LIKE :search"` does that make it easier? that's what I've been trying to tell you all along. the other guy is "guessing".

Comment: sorry I am still confused I will close out the question and figure out how to accomplish this a bit more. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you can't do compound predicates in sql server. Your comment above still has syntax errors.

Comment: @SeanLange I made an error, that's what I meant to write. OP should use what you wrote then. Let's see a green tick next to that ;-)

Comment: you have another syntax error Donny; your `catch`, is missing a closing brace. Again, error reporting would have signaled an unexpected end of file notice/warning. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides what's already been said about the way you're using `WHERE` and `LIKE` in comments and in Sean's answer, am adding this as an additional answer:

Your `catch` is missing its closing brace

```
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
    die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );
    } 
    ^ added
```

Using error reporting would have trigged an unexpected end of file warning.

Plus, in PDO, there shouldn't be any spaces

```
"sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=systems_requests"
```

and could be a contributing factor; remove them.

```
"sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database=systems_requests"
```

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

References:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Your query requires either an `AND` or `OR` and the column, depending on the search criteria.

However, I am unsure of your use of `PDO::PARAM_INT`, if your search is a string, then that will fail.

- **You also failed to query.**

Read the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php

Example from the manual:

```
$sql = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM SomeTable";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      echo $row['LastName'].", ".$row['FirstName']."<br />";
}
```

In your case:

```
$query  = "select * from requests where comments like '%" . $var1 . "%'";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $db, $query );
```

You also need to use a conditional statement for your POST array.

I.e.:

```
if(!empty($_POST['var1'])){
  $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
}
```

---

**Rewrite:**

```
<?php
require_once("../includes/db_connect.php");

if(!empty($_POST['var1'])){
  $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
}

else{ echo "It is empty."; exit; }

$query  = "select * from requests where comments like '%".$var1."%'";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $db, $query );

if( $stmt === false)
{
     echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


  while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo 'Id: '.$row['id'];
    echo '<br/> name: '.$row['name'];
    echo '<br/> lanId: '.$row['lanId'];
    echo '<br/> comments: '.$row['comments'];

}


?>
```

Comment: I changed up the whole code it is up at the edit section I am able to get the page but not able to fetch the data now

Comment: @Donny I made a few edits.

Comment: I made the changes I get different error An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query.

Comment: @Donny reload my answer and look under **Rewrite**. If that doesn't work, I'll be quite stumped.

Comment: i still get that error Error in query preparation/execution. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. ) )  I am little stumped also

Comment: @Donny make sure your connection isn't failing you. Check the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php and as I stated in my answer, there shouldn't be any spaces in your PDO's DSN. also do a `var_dump();`

Comment: connection is working other pages are able to access it i took all the spaces out

Comment: @Donny Try removing `where comments like '%".$var1."%'` what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your select look more like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM requests WHERE status='Received' and [columnName] LIKE ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(?, '%' . $var1 . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Without that, there is no way for the query to know what column you are searching.

Comment: I get error unexpected syntax ? I am trying to grasp how to search the entire table but can't figure it out yet

Comment: I think you are missing an AND before the [columnName]. This is the exact same issue as the original query. It is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Fixed (oops).  And I may have been amiss in replacing the :search with a ?.  @Donny...  I don't know that there IS a way to do that without making a series of OR clauses for every column you could search.  I don't think there is a wildcard method to be used across columns.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason several people are having a hard time figuring out the issue here. This would be the query that is now at syntactically correct. I have no idea what column you are trying to include in your search but change out SomeColumn with your actual column name and this should be there.

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM requests WHERE status='Received' AND SomeColumn LIKE :search";
```

Comment: well I've been trying to tell him from the beginning to "hopefully" teach them using links I've provided, rather than popping in an answer.

Comment: But the OP was getting more and more confused. Many times especially in something new it helps the understanding to see it actually work after trying it several times. :)

Comment: yeah, I made a mistake in my example (we all phoque up sometimes); I went too fast. However, my links should have provided them with the proper syntax to use. Those can't be wrong ;-)

Comment: only thing with the links they are for mysql I am using MSSQl so I really can't go by the link you sent me no big deal I will have to learn another way of creating a search feature in php with mssql. I know how to do it in php and mysql thats easier

Comment: LOL no problem at all. And of course we all make those mistakes sometimes. I am sure for the OP the confusion was getting incrementally worse because they were being spoon fed queries but they were all still incorrect.

Comment: I can't help you with php syntax, I can't even spell that let alone do anything with it.

Comment: There is one thing though about `sqlsrv:server=$serverName ;` in PDO, there shouldn't be any spaces. Notice the one in there? and possibly the other in `sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database` before "Database". Plus, no idea why they want to use `PDO::PARAM_INT`, for a possible "string"? And `bindValue` could be `bindParam`.

Comment: *groan* - I just noticed a syntax error for their catch brace; it's missing. Error reporting,.... again... should have signaled an unexpected end of file notice. Most likely a 60% contributor to the problem. I pasted his code in my editor and BAM; missing brace.

Comment: I changed it up look at the edited question above now I am able to get the field to show up but when I type and submit data i get this error sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. The OP was struggling with the syntax of their query and this is at least syntatically correct. Whatever, this place is so finicky sometimes.

Comment: @SeanLange I know, and I wouldn't be surprised if my answer were to also get a downvote.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well if it does at least my upvote will offset it. Your answer certainly answers more of the specifics for this problem. As I said I know less than nothing about php so I am no help with that part of the solution.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks Sean. I sure hope we all get to see the light at the end of the tunnel. This one has got the OP and I stumped.

Comment: @Fred-ii- count me in as a third...but mostly as a spectator.